# "Compilation failed for data model at path" when compiling Core Data model after upgrading to lion

Tags: core-data

After upgrading to lion, the following error prevents successful compilation of a core data model:

> core-data-model/MyModel.xcdatamodeld:0: error: Compilation
>   failed for data model at path
>   'resources/MyModel.momd/MyModel.mom'

This is the result of executing the following command:

> /Developer/usr/bin/momc core-data-model/MyModel.xcdatamodeld resources/MyModel.momd

Note that this command is executing in a custom build script independently of xcode, and that it ran without problems before upgrading to Lion.

I've read of model compilation errors after upgrading to Lion (for instance see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788215/data-model-version-compile-error-after-upgrading-to-lion-xcode4-1) question), but the solutions detailed there do not seem to apply.

Anyone else encounter problems manually invoking model compilation after upgrading to Lion? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out - it seems like the object model compiler now expects the destination path to be absolute. This works:

> /Developer/usr/bin/momc core-data-model/MyModel.xcdatamodeld
>   /Users/amos/projects/my-project/resources/MyModel.momd

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting this error because I had a bad inverse relationship in my model :
[image]

I fixed it by splitting it into two inverse relationships :
[image]

Comment: My issue was similar to this.  I had named one of the relationships with the same name as another relationship in a parent table.