# Compilation failed for data model at path after upgrading Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, datamodel

After upgrading to Xcode 4.3.2 I have started getting the following error when i do a build:

```
Compilation failed for data model at path '/Users/Administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ffeggcadwojrwacrwosvadafamrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Data.momd/Data.mom'
```

This was not happening before the upgrade and if i check out the same project on machine running the previous version of Xcode it works fine. No Errors.

I have found a couple of similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993760/compilation-failed-for-data-model-at-path-when-compiling-core-data-model-after) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788215/data-model-version-compile-error-after-upgrading-to-lion-xcode4-1) but none of the answers have helped at all. From the error message the file path it gives doesn't contain a file so i'm guessing its a property somewhere that i need to change but i just can't find it.

Please help, thanks.

EDIT: On further investigation, i can stop it from erroring if i remove certain entities from the data model file, we are currently using a large pre created sqlite file to load data so i could recreate the data model file but that would mean recreating the sqlite which would be a bit of a pain. Anyone know why certain entities cause this?