# error in compiling .xcdatamodel

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

i have xcode 4.3 with ios 5.1 and trying to compile and run the project, but it gives error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc failed with exit code 6
```

i found something in ["Data Model Version Compile".. error after upgrading to Lion (Xcode4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788215/data-model-version-compile-error-after-upgrading-to-lion-xcode4-1) but it doesn't provide me any suitable solution. It say's to delete unnecessary .xcdatamodel-directories and i did, but i still stuck up there with same issue. Other thing i found that the extension is changed in new xcode its '.xcdatamodeld' instead of '.xcdatamodel'. I copied content content of '.xcdatamodel' file and put in to '.xcdatamodeld' and added to xcode but it gave error at some where else that persistence store might exist. what should i do to run this project..
     thanks in advance!!!